# How to fix corrupted encoded words using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, string-decoding

In one of my database table I found some corrupted words like:

**`No├â┬½l, jap├â┬│n, ├à┬Üwiata`**

Which I later found should be as:

**`Noël, japón, świata`**

Anyone know how to convert them back to normal using **PHP**

Comment: do you know why they have been corrupted? Maybe due to wrong charset in table or was it the php insert/update?

Comment: Yes @Micallef! 
Most probably due to a database transfer! 
Now collation in the raw is set as "utf8_general_ci" 
But now I just want to use the data in the table and not going to insert anymore. 
Is there anyway to get them back to normal?

Comment: you may use `preg_replace` to replace the characters if they are consistently incorrect

Comment: Well @Micallef, there are lot of characters. Hard to find which represents which. Latin to Arabic –

Comment: any chance you can redo the database transfer?

Comment: Yes @Micallef, I'll give a try and tell you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can check if the problem is related to the character encoding using `iconv` - [Check the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#94946)

Comment: I have don a mistake while importing, did not set the encoding while importing!

`mysql -u USERNAME  -pPASSWORD --default_character_set utf8  DATABASE < file.sql`

Now everything is back to normal

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not revertible by using php conversion. I've just made a PHP script which tries all combinations, more than once (up to 5 times) and none of them yields "japón". So it's not possible.

script:

```
<?php
$encodings=mb_list_encodings();
foreach($encodings as $enc_to) {
    foreach($encodings as $enc_from) {
        $str="No├â┬½l, jap├â┬│n, ├à┬Üwiata";
        for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
            $str=mb_convert_encoding($str,$enc_to,$enc_from);
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i): ".$str."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + html_entity_decode: ".html_entity_decode($str)."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + htmlspecialchars_decode: ".htmlspecialchars_decode($str)."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + urldecode: ".urldecode($str)."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + htmlentities: ".htmlentities($str)."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + htmlspecialchars: ".htmlspecialchars($str)."\n";
            echo "$enc_from -> $enc_to ($i) + urlencode: ".urlencode($str)."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

... grepping the output catches no "japón"

Comment: Or is it encoded twice @Alex? Like ś first changed to &#347; and then to ├à┬Ü

Comment: I've improved the script (look, it tries to encode and decode in different ways) and it doesn't catch it anyway.